# How to use std::invoke_result_t to get return type of a function

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to implement a flavored `for_each()`, it will stop iteration when the passed in function returns `false`. If the passed in function doesn't return a Boolean value, then run through as `std::for_each()`.

I'm having some difficulty getting the returned type of function parameter, I tried to use `std::invoke_result_t`, but it complains:

> no member named 'type' in 'std::__1::invoke_result<...

In the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) on C++ reference, it always passes in the `Arg` type for the function. But in my case, shouldn't type `F` already contain all the type information of the whole function?

```cpp
template<class C, class F>
void for_each(C container, F&& f)
{
    for (auto const& v : container)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<F>, bool>)
        {
            if (not std::forward<F>(f)(v))
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::forward<F>(f)(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add main function to show an example for using your for_each

Comment: `F` could have multiple `operator()` overloads with different parameter lists. You need to specify the parameters so the compiler knows which one you want.

Comment: It looks like you probably want `std::invoke_result_t<F, decltype(v)>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the first part of the question of "how to make it work" is to include the argument type(s) - in this case, probably something like `std::invoke_result_t<F, decltype(v)>`.

As for "shouldn't type F already contain all the type information of the whole function?" - as another commenter mentioned, it's possible for `F` to be a function object with multiple `operator()` overloads, so the answer is no.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. std::invoke_result_t<F, decltype(v)> worked. Now I realized a function object can have several operator() taking different types.